# assign asp page variable value to php variable

Tags: php, asp.net

I have asp label in my asp page and its text is some my specific text. Now there I want to read this asp label text in PHP page. Means I want to get asp page label text in PHP page in a variable. Is there any built in function or another method to do this? I have tried much in PHP and also I am new to PHP so unable to do this. Is there any method to send the label text to PHP page or get the label text in PHP page? If is there any way to do this in vb.net or c# to send this label text to PHP then please share this with me or tell something other in PHP to get that value.

**update**

```
<asp:label id="lblemail" runat="server" text="malik.adeel"></label>
    <a href="http://sml.com.pk/sfpl/milk.php" target="_blank">Milk Receipt Dashboard</a>
```

I am calling PHP page in anchor tag and above is the label which have text. Now I want to take label text when I call the PHP page and also assign this text to PHP variable.

Comment: Erm... What? You're not making any sense.

Comment: How do you mix ASP.NET and PHP? :O

Comment: can you give here the code ? How you have mix them up ?

Comment: Quite a confusing question. Try to improve it by using other words, giving examples... ;)

Comment: Mr See Below same thing is happening by @RayG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend sending the value to the php page with a URL parameter.

In ASP.NET you could pass the parameter by doing something like this:

```
Response.Redirect("YourPage.php?variableName=" + variableValue);
```

Then in your php page, retrieve it by doing something like this:

```
$value = $_GET['variableName'];
```

Comment: Try replacing your anchor tag with the following. It should insert the value of lblemail.text as a parameter in the URL named myParam. `<a href="http://sml.com.pk/sfpl/milk.php?myParam=<%=lblemail.Text %>" target="_blank">Milk Receipt Dashboard</a>`